# compile issue using C99 does it to have a scope around each if?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I thought the following code should compile with VS'2013 C compiler, but it look like an identifier definition after an `if` without bracket (1 line `if` ...) isn't working

Doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
1>..\..\common\threadpool.c(82): error C2275: 'test_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          ..\..\common\threadpool.c(75) : see declaration of 'test_t'
1>..\..\common\threadpool.c(82): error C2065: 'pool' : undeclared identifier


typedef struct { int j; } test_t;

int f(test_t **p_pool, int i)
{
    if (i <= 0)
        return -1;

    test_t *pool;   
    *p_pool = pool;

    return i;
}
```

Works

```
typedef struct { int j; } test_t;

int f(test_t **p_pool, int i)
{
    if (i <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    test_t *pool;   
    *p_pool = pool;

    return i;
}
```

Have you a work-around in order to build a huge legacy code base where that kind of code can occur a lot of time ?

Comment: Could you post the precise error message?

Comment: An SSCCE is needed here.

Comment: Please post complete and minimal code that demonstrates the issue, as the code you posted does not.

Comment: I added an SSCCE comming from my code. and FYI if I replace `test_t` by a simple `int` in that case it's ok without the bracket !

Comment: Note: `pool` is uninitialized pointer, and you assign the uninitialized pointer value to `*p_pool`. This is not sane code, , maybe that is what is throwing the compiler off.

Comment: @hyde Nope, that's not it.

Comment: Added the exact compiler error message

Comment: Is compiling everything as C++ an option?

Comment: Does it fix it to move the line `test_t *pool;` to before the `if`?

Comment: I don't see the SSCCE, error messages indicate lines 75-82 and there are only a handful of lines in the posted code so far

Comment: @MattMcNabb Paste the code in the question into a file, compile as see, observe the error messages.

Comment: My point is that the error message you post should correspond to the SSCCE, not to the original code from which you generated the SSCCE

Comment: Possible things to try to get around apparent compiler bug, which could then be applied to codebase with search-replace / rename refactoring: remove `_t` suffix from typedefed name (it's reserved in POSIX, so there could be some funny compiler code path triggered by it), or remove the whole typedef and use `struct test`, or try adding dummy statement just before `test_t *pool;` so it's not the first thing after the if-then. Additionally, check that there's no `#define` funniness going on by asking compiler to save preprossessor output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is valid and should compile. That it does not indicates that this is a compiler bug. You should submit a bug report to Microsoft.

To workaround this you would need to do one of the following:

- Get a corrected version of the compiler from Microsoft.
- Use a different compiler, a real C99 compiler for instance.
- Modify the code to side-step the erroneous compilation error.

Comment: I Think the question is asking for a work-around, and submitting a bug report might not work quite fast enough even in the best case...

Comment: As I read it, question is asking workaround which does not involve modifying many files in "a huge legacy code base".

Comment: @hyde And that workaround is? I presume your comments imply that there is one.

Comment: In fact I think that there is no workaround and as an echo to the answer I opened a bug ticket through MS connect web site. But thank to everybody in fact you help me to confirm that it aws a bug related to the "_t" in the type name.